# Turn a queue either into embed or one single message

Tags: discord.js

I have this code for a queue in my music bot:

```
else if(cmd === 'ws'){
            message.channel.send('Warteschlange:')
            for(i = 0; i < server_queue.songs.length; i++){
                message.channel.send('***' + (i+1) + ': ' + server_queue.songs[i].title + '***');
            }
        }
```

now I want to do a for-loop to either add fields to an embed, or to somehow get a \n in there so that my bot doesnt have to send a message for every song in queue.
(Note: the cmd === 'ws' is for when the command is "ws" (german abbrev. for queue)

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the concept down, iterating over each value, and then all you have to do is put it inside an embed context.

I basically created a new embed, labeling the Author, Color, Thumbnail, and Timestamp beforehand. Then I iterated over the `server_queue` array and then for each song, I would add a field to the embed to represent that song.

Here's an example code that you can use. You'll have to modify it to your current needs. You could consider adding the song's artist as the second value in the field. I simply just wrote "something else" as a filler.

Code:

```js
if (command === 'ws') {
    let server_queue = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Warteschlange:")
        .setColor("#000000")
        .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL())
        .setTimestamp(Date.now());
    
    server_queue.forEach(song => {
        embed.addField(song, 'something else')
    })
    message.channel.send(embed);
}
```